# POSTMAN COLLECTION RUNNER: passing the all body post request as a variable?

Tags: variables, postman-collection-runner

I have a POST request  template - instead putting all the JSON body i put a variable: `{{bodyRequest}}`

[image]

now i have a json file that looks like this(Below code bloc) that i upload in my collection runner as data json: my intention is to fetch {{bodyResponse}} from the iteration and make the post call in the api.

```
[

{   "{{bodyRequest}}":  
   {
    "order": {          
            "order_date":"{{$timestamp}}",
            "order_number":"{{$guid}}",
            "reference":"Scenario1",
            "destination":
                    {
                        "name":"test",
                        "phone":"00000",
                        "email":"test@test.com",
                        "company":"My Company",
                        "building":"My Building",
                        "street":"my street",
                        "suburb":"my sububr",
                        "post_code":"my postcode",
                          },
            }

    }
}


]
```

Then i click run
Open Collection Runner
Add Data file in Format JSON (above in code)
declare it as Json
run collection

Error Log
Request Body:"{{bodyRequest}} "

instead the all payload

thank you so much

Franco

Comment: Can you try a file without "$"?
The JSON file is an array of objects, with each object having key/value pairs. Postman supports only simple numerical and string values inside the JSON file. Download a sample JSON file to find out how it looks like.

Comment: i can post many scenarios i know but no the all request body as variable ?


[
{   "TEST SCENARIO": "test 1",
   "reference": "test",
   "order_number": "{{randomOrderNumber}}",
   "order_date" : "{{$timestamp}}",
   "name" :  "test",
   "phone" : "000000",
   "email":"test.uk@test.com",
   "company": "My Company",
   "building": "My Building",
   "street": "47 Bowman Road",
   "suburb": "CALOUNDRA",
   "post_code": "4551",
   "state": "QLD",
   "city": "Mount Sheridan",
   "country": "Australia",
   "delivery_instructions": "Leave at front-door" 
}]

Comment: I don't remember if postman can understand {{$timestamp}}. To replace a variable it must be {{randomOrderNumber}} without the $. Try with the file from postman example https://www.getpostman.com/samples/test_data_file.json

Comment: Hey Graciano yes  {{$timestamp} works and randomOrderNumber as well as I use a global variable that does use the function Math; but those are not the problems!!!!  the load with fields works perfectly  fine ...the problem i am trying to solve is  how can i make call a Runner Collection if i declare a body request variable ?  literally load an entire body request . read the main question please.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files ?

Comment: I am using already collection data - the problem relates to input. If passing some of the payload fields as parameter from a file it will work;
it will NOT work if passing entire payload or array of object. it seems that postman cannot handle complex object and only can handle single field.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do here - It's a little bit confusing from the way that you have worded the question.

Comment: I have a post request body declared as a variable in the postman ui (format json).

I create a data file to run within the data collection
And he collection from the ui .

Can the data file contains the all payload ?

Make sense?